# Testing POST method with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, http-post, parameters

I want to test a `POST` method which only receives from the client-side a token, verify the validity of that token and based on this it creates or not a record in the database (it doesn't matter the record).
In controller

```
def create 
    uri = URI('https://graph.facebook.com/me')
    params = { access_token: params[:access_token] }
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    ...
    # parse the response and create the user
    ...
end
```

In test controller

```
describe "POST #create" do
    it "response with forbidden error code" do
        post :create, access_token: 'xxxxx'
        expect(response.status).to eq(403)
    end
end
```

The test method gives the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

and it points to this line of code from the create method:

```
params = { access_token: params[:access_token] }
```

Also, when I test this method in Postman I got the same error.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just for trying, can you rename the hash in your controller for other name different than 'params'?

Comment: The solution was to make a private function `fb_user_params` which returns the allowed parameters and to rewrite the 

`params = { access_token: params[:access_token] }`
in
`params = { access_token: fb_user_params}`